# ios6 storyboard how to create a segue to display a web page

Tags: ios6

I am trying to display a web page in a web view  upon tap on an imageView in a detail controller
I am correctly detecting the tap in the detail view

```
//The tap event handling method
- (void)onTapimageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //NSLog(@"Tap detected");
    if(nil != self.analysis.webURL) {
        NSURL *analysisURL = [NSURL URLWithString: self.analysis.webURL];
    }
}
```

I am a little bit lost upon deciding how to segue to a web view 
I created another View Controller with an UIWebView, an UINavigationBar and a close button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `performSegue:`. Then pass the info along in `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: And you might be helped by reading my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_storyboards

Comment: running fine ...  ios6 is actually simpler than all previous versions... I was lost among all suggestions found googling out